# Razor Pages not finding subfolder index page

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

This may be a stupid question but i can't seem to get a Razor Pages project to locate index files placed in subfolders properly.

Based on this introduction to razor pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

The following structure is valid.

```
File name and path                  matching URL
/Pages/Index.cshtml                 / or /Index
/Pages/Contact.cshtml               /Contact
/Pages/Store/Contact.cshtml         /Store/Contact
/Pages/Store/Index.cshtml           /Store or /Store/Index
```

The last one listed there is what i'm having problems with. It seems that if i try and specify `/Store` it will not manage to locate the right page. If i specify `/Store/Index` it will work though..

Here's how to replicate this.

1. Create ASP.NET Core WebApp project with RazorPages
2. Create a folder under pages called `Store`
3. Create a razor page under that folder called `Index`
4. Update the `_Layout` page to point to `asp-page="/Store"`
5. Try and run the app and click on the navigation link and see it won't load the page
6. Update the link to `asp-page="/Store/Index"` and run the app to see that the link is properly routed now

Am i completely missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asp-page` attribute requires the name of the page. It is not a URL. Since the page is named Index, you need to include that. The "name" of the page is basically its relative path rooted in Pages, minus the file extension. But the important part to note is that you must include "Index" when trying to link to a file named *Index*.

Comment: Seems very counterintuitive when all they had to do was handle the index use case and be done with it..